# Attach environmental variable to Lambda outside of resource declaration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a 3rd party module that creates an `aws_lambda_function` and returns function's `arn`. I have no access to module code, but I need to further customize the function by adding an environmental variable. Is it possible to attach environmental variable outside of function declaration? Or is there other way to achieve the same?

Comment: You can do it manually through the Lambda console, that's outside the resource declaration, not sure if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Not really. The environment variables are part of the resource so any workaround would be pretty awful (eg using a null resource with a local-exec provisioner to use the AWS CLI to set the environment variables of the Lambda given the ARN). Why do you need the third party module and why can't you change it? Can you not just fork the module instead? And it seems odd that it wouldn't allow you to set environment variables if it's really meant to be a useful module.

Comment: Haven't validated this but you may be able to update the Lambda function configuration's environment variables without touching anything else (or re-uploading the function code). You'll have to get the current environment variables (e.g. `aws lambda get-function-configuration`) then modify the returned environment variables then update the function config with *just* the environment variables (e.g. `aws lambda update-function-configuration --environment xyz ...`). Obviously, your IAM credentials will need permission for both actions on that Lambda function.

Comment: Example: `aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myfunc --environment Variables='{Description="My function",Version="1.1",Owner="yuriyg"}'`